# Tracking objects in a 3D environment with 2D HUD icons

Tags: java, opengl, vector, jogl, hud

I am attempting to have a 2D HUD which has icons that track the location on the screen of 3D objects behind the HUD in a 3D environment.

**Reasoning:** Sometimes you cannot see a 3D object (too far away or off screen) but you still want to know where it is.

**Issue:** 3D scene is using a perspective matrix to transform it, giving it depth (z-axis), the HUD is strictly 2D (xy-plane). Because of the depth, the 2D HUD cannot properly track objects when they are farther/closer away.

**What I want:** A way to get a 2D Vector [(x,y) pos] of where to put an icon so that it is centered where the 3D object in the background would be.

**Example of all objects in an xy-plane (z=0):**

You can see that as the objects get farther away from the center, the Icon (circle thing in white) is more off center.
[image: Example 1]

**Example of objects with increasing depths (farther from center == deeper):**

You can see that the HUD thinks 3D objects are in the same plane still.
[image: Example 2]

**Pseudo-Code:**

.getPos() gets the Vector (x,y,z)

```
lookAtObj = Object.getPos() - camera.getPos() // lookAt vector from camera to the object
icon.pos = Orthogonal Component of lookAtObj on camera.get_lookAt()
```

**My Perspective Matrix:**

```
// Function call in the OpenGL draw() method
FloatMatrix proj = FloatMatrix.getPerspectiveMatrix( this.fov, this.width, this.height, 0.1f, 200.0f );

// Function
public static FloatMatrix getPerspectiveMatrix( Double fov, float w, float h, float near, float far ){
    float asp = w/h;
    float fov_cos = (float) Math.cos( fov / 2.0d );
    float fov_sin = (float) Math.sin( fov / 2.0d );
    float fov_cot = fov_cos/fov_sin;
    float a_0  = fov_cot/asp;
    float a_3  = (far + near)/(near-far);
    float a_43 = (2.0f * far * near)/(near-far);
    float[] an = {
            a_0,  0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, fov_cot, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,    a_3,  -1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,    a_43, 0.0f,
    };
    return new FloatMatrix( an, 4, 4 );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. You can use [`gluProject`](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/jogl-2.x-docs/javax/media/opengl/glu/GLU.html#gluProject%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double%5B%5D,%20int,%20double%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20double%5B%5D,%20int%29). It will take a given modelview, projection, and viewport transform, and a 3D point, and apply the inverse and spit out a 2D point in window coordinates for you (apologies for minor typos, just typing this here):

```
double myX = ..., myY = ..., myZ = ...; // your object's 3d coordinates
double[] my2DPoint = new double[2]; // will contain 2d window coords when done

double[] modelview = new double[16];
double[] projection = new double[16];
int[] viewport = new int[4];

gl.glGetDoublev(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview, 0);
gl.glGetDoublev(GL2.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection, 0);
gl.glGetIntegerv(GL2.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);
glu.gluProject(myX, myY, myZ, modelview, 0, projection, 0,
               viewport, 0, my2DPoint, 0);

// now my2DPoint[0] is window x, and my2DPoint[1] is window y
```

After you do this, you'll have your 3D point in 2D window coordinates. Then simply switch your projection over to a 2D orthogonal projection, in window pixels, and draw your HUD in 2D space.

For performance, if you have multiple HUD items to draw per frame; just get the modelview/projection/viewport once per frame (or, even better, invalidate your cached ones if you change them and re-query only as needed) and reuse them in subsequent calls to `gluProject`.

Comment: @MichaelMitchell If you want to understand the math, check out the official docs for [`gluProject`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluProject.xml) which shows the matrix equation used down at the bottom. For a very in-depth description that will give you a full understanding of the math involved plus some, check out http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html. This link shows you all the steps OpenGL takes to get from a 3D position to a final rendered window coordinate.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for linking those!